# Proper Hibernate nested transactions handling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transaction-isolation

I am sure that I am missing something, but I don't know exactly what...

Giving the following snippet:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass self;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        self = applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doA(User user) {
        ...
        if (condition) {
            self.doB(user);
            throw new SecurityException();
        }
        user.setRandomField("x");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doB(User user) {
        ...
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

What do I know about `@Transactional` is that if it is used, is redundant to call `repository.save(entity)`.

What I am trying to do, is to process an entity from a transactional method, and if there is a breaking condition, call a new method (annotated with `REQUIRES_NEW`) that will update some fields of the entity and save it. The root method (`doA`) then throws an exception. FYI: the `@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = SecurityException.class)` is not an option in this situation.

For using this commiting mechanism, instead of creating a new bean just with one method I just injected the current bean into a variable just called `self`, therefore I can use the bean proxy for transaction management.

The odd thing is that if I am removing from `doB` the `save` call, when `doA` transaction is rollbacked because of the `SecurityException`, the changes performed by `doB` are rollbacked as well. But if I let it in there, this is working as expected.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do not pass User instance in the doB(). Pass an Id instead and read the User from the repo internally. I am not sure how the attached entity is handled between the different sessions.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :) Thanks dude! That was it!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do not pass User instance in the doB(). 
Pass an Id instead and read the User from the repo internally. I am not sure how the attached entity is handled between the different sessions.